# BLACK DUCK - Open Source Scan result misleading

Tags: security, license, open-source, inventory-software

My company started using `Black Duck version 2018.12.4` and i would like to understand if i made a mistake or if i found a bug.

I did the follwing:

1. Start Black Duck Scanner Desktop with Scanner CLI version 2018.12.4.
2. Connect to our server
3. Created a new Scan

   1. picked a folder where the code lies
   2. entered a scan name
   3. entered an project name that already existed at our server
   4. started the scan
4. Upload the scan to the server
5. Log in to our Black Duck server
6. Open our project and view the listed components

### Result - Erorr / Bug ?

- Expected: Only components that belong to this project and the linked / mapped scan show up in this list
- Actual: components from a previous scan and another project show up

Below are screenshots where i marked the wrongly listed components.

#### List of scans and mapped project

Here you can see the two scans and two projects i did:

- CMS Scan was my first scan and first project
- DAM Scan was my second scan and my second project

scans from others were erased.

[image: List of Scans and mapped projects]

#### Components inside the DAM project

This screen shows the components that do belong to the project and the related scan. There seems to be an eror - see above Result / Error.

[image: Components inside one project]

Comment: Have you contacted their support team? Presumably you have a valid licensed and as you're new users a support contract as well?

Comment: Yes i am in contact with their support team now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about commercial software with a support contract in place.

Comment: After reading [on-topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) i assume that you consider this question off-topic because of `issues specific to corporate IT support`. I believe this question to be of value for all users that are considering using black duck. I am willing to self answer in case i get a reply from the vendor.

Comment: Correct. Though nobody else has voted similarly, so it might just be me :-)

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to your support request?

Comment: No i did not. Currently i have to deal with other things. But your questions reminds me that i will ping them again.

Comment: Did you get a resolution to this problem?